# Let $ABCDEF$ be a hexagon such that the diagonals $AD,BE,CF$ intersect at point $O$.

Tags: geometry, contest-math, problem-solving, polygons

> Let $ABCDEF$ be a hexagon such that the diagonals $AD,BE,CF$ intersect at point $O$, and the area of the triangle formed by any three adjacent points is $2$. Find the area of the hexagon.

**What I Tried**: Here is a picture :-

[image]

I drew some kind of an irregular hexagon for convenience, but I am thinking that is this true only for a certain regular hexagon? In this case the triangles are definitely don't have equal area as $2$, is it possible only for a regular hexagon, along with diagonals $AD,BE,CF$ concurring at $O$? If it is true (which I am not sure), then it is great, but I have found no way to prove it.

As another way, by adding and subtracting areas, I was only able to conclude that $[\Delta BFD] = [\Delta AEC]$, other than that I have no idea.

Can anyone help me here? Thank You.

Comment: What is meant by adjacent points? $3$ adjacent vertices?

Comment: Yes, $3$ adjacent vertices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that the area of the triangle formed by any three adjacent points are equal, there are a lot of parallel lines in this hexagon. For example:

$$[\triangle ABC] = [\triangle BCD] \implies BC//AD \implies [\triangle BOC] = [\triangle ABC] = [\triangle BCD]$$

Using this property for each side of the hexagon, the area is $2 \times 6$.

EDIT: Found a squished hexagon with concurrent diagonals which are parallel to the sides:
[image]

Comment: Great, I never thought about that. Also you might think about the fact that the regular hexagon is the only hexagon satisfying these as well as having 3 diagonals concurrent?

Comment: Concurrent diagonals: no. Concurrent diagonals *and* diagonals parallel to both opposite sides? That I wish to investigate.

Comment: Found it. ${ }$

Comment: (Adding on, ABO can be any triangle. This is the setup for tessallations of the plane.)